# Draw Button at the buttom of the View

Tags: android

Hy!!

I want to have a button at the button and centered on the view in a linearlayout.

non working example:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@+id/login_btnew" android:text="Make a new Account"></Button>
```

Solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the following `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/login_btnew" 
    android:text="Make a new Account"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that for example in the following fashion:

I have the linear layout you mentioned on top I have scroll view and at the bottom I have th button. Using android:layout_weight="1000" for the scroll view and android:layout_weight="1" for the button gives the desired result. Center the button using android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/login_btnew"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Make a new Account"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with layout_weight and put in another linearlayout for the layouting.

You could do sth like (pseudo-code)

```
<linearlayout layout_height=fill_parent layout_with=fill_parent>
    #the "top" fields 
    <linearlayout layout_height=fill_parent layout_with=fill_parent layout_weight=1>
        <elem1/><elem2/><elem3/>   
    </linearlayout>
    #the bottom field (button)   
    <button layout_height=wrap_content layout_with=wrap_content layout_gravity=center_horizontal gravity=center ></button> 
</linearlayout>
```